# User should be notified when a competing answer has been posted

Tags: feature-request, answers, notifications

I would like to request a feature for Stack Overflow.

Say I have answered a question. If an other user posts an answer to the same question, then I would like to be notified that "Some user has answered the same question". That way, I could check the other answer, and see if I can improve mine.

Currently, I need to check the answers manually by refreshing the page again and again. If there is a long list of answers, this is a tough task.

Comment: You could put the question as a favorite and monitor it that way.

Comment: In that case I need to make all questions favorite for which I have answered. Then list of favorite questions will be too long, and it will be tough, if need to search particular favorite question, which is actually favorite to me.

Comment: Note to Devs: If this becomes a feature, please make it optional with the default set to `OFF`.  That's too many notifications.

Comment: Isn't there already an Ajax notification that pops down saying "# new answers have been posted", with a link to refresh the question?

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn : it show for my questions. For other's question?

Comment: @Gaurav: It also displays for other questions that you're viewing, but that one is a bit different. Or maybe I'm just misinterpreting your question here...

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn : I am sorry. But probably I am not able to find it. Is there any other setting?

Comment: It's not a setting, it happens automatically. You do need to be viewing a page (or at least have it open in a browser tab).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My recommendation would be to leave your answer as improved as it could be, and stop monitoring the question. In my opinion, the quality of your answer shouldn't depend on the quality of other answers to the same question. If you are after the rep, then "answer your best, and let it rest" ©.