# Notifications for posts in questions you have posted an accepted answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

I want to suggest a feature that I would really love to see implemented.

Whenever you answer someone's question and get your answer accepted I would like to see new answers pop up in the notification area. Why would I want that - as it usually happens, the accepted answer (if there is one) gets viewed much more than other answers below but other solutions may be more useful/suitable for different situations, so if I could monitor this, I would at least edit my answer to refer readers to the answer below so they could notice it too.

In any case, this could be a checkbox in settings that some of us may use. I don't think it would be hard to implement and won't make a big difference in performance!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117988/152859

Comment: I've seen this question too, but what I want to say in my suggestion covers a bit more long-run solution. For example if the question is one or two years old and the technology changes, the accepted answer may not be the best solution "up-to-date" anymore. The question linked covers more of a "recent question answer" where author mentions refreshing the page after giving an answer.